# Batch Scripting: Pass argument password containing caret character

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, arguments, caret

So I have the folloing batch script (**test.bat**):

```
@echo off

set usernameArgument=%1
set passwordArgument=%2

echo Password Argument: %passwordArgument%
```

In the CMD if I call this using a password argument that has a caret "^" character the caret character gets stripped:

```
C:\> test.bat UserName Pass^Word
```

OUTPUT: `Password Argument: PassWord`

Is there a way I can get the value of the passwordArgument field (%2) with the caret character,

NOTE: I have a limitation, since this is a password I don't want to pass in something like this Pass^^^^Word I would like to find a solution that allows me to just pass in Pass^Word as the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is an escaped character in cmd. if you've to use this in your password then you have to use it two time i.e., `^^` to get one in password.

E.g., if you enter `pass^^word`, then your password will be `pass^word`.

Alternative could be to use `"` double-quotes around password. Like: "pass^Word". That's going to solve your problem.

Hope that will help.